# Windows 10 Pro 18362.19h1_r.190318-1202 / HP 840 G5: Emoji picker not working

Tags: windows

I've googled this issue extensively but none of the 5/6 fixes I've tried work.  My emoji picker simply doesn't respond (Winkey + .).  The hourglass appears briefly, as if it's loading something, and if I press the hotkey return/enter keypresses don't have any effect until I hit escape to close (?) the ghost emoji screen.

My laptop is the HP 840 G5... I'm at my wits' end with this one.  Any advice would be very welcome.  Sorry it's such a known issue with so many fixes; none of them have worked for me.  I'm on US settings in language/region; my EnableExpressiveInputShellHotkey reg keys are all set to 1, I've apparently forced it to work with every language via WinAero and its "Enable emoji picker for all languages" option, etc.

I don't use them much but for SMSes they're pretty handy.  Thanks for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from the accessibility (white-on-blacck) theme to the normal Windows theme reinstates the regular Winkey + . behaviour.  When I then toggle it back to the accessibility theme it -- still works?!  Might have to toggle between accessibility → regular → accessibility themes on startup.  Very strange.